# Como usar un token permanente con Http POST en servicios REST

Tags: c#, rest, post, tokens, http-post

Buenas,

Estoy intentando hacer un POST de un Json con un token permanente, pero siempre me da `error 401 unauthorized`, código:

```
    public static async Task<Uri> CrearitemAsync(Item item)
    {
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", AuthToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("items/" + IdProvider, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return response.Headers.Location;
    }
    }
```

también probé con:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken);
```

y con:

```
 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ejemplo.com/items/id");
        httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "IDENTITY_KEY" + AuthToken);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

El token parece estar bien, es un string alfanumérico con todo minúsculas,

**actualización** la key que me han pasado es: IDENTITY_KEY
pero me sigue fallando

alguna idea?

Comment: Falta el tag sobre la tecnología usada ¿C#?

Comment: ¿Tienes forma de acceder a los logs del servicio al que estas enviando peticiones? Pudiera ser que el token es inválido, te recomiendo utilizar alguna herramienta para hacer peticiones HTTP y poder modificar las cabeceras facilmente. 
Te recomiendo utilizar [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) para lograr realizar tu petición y luego inspeccionar las peticiones salientes de tu código utilizando [RequestBin](https://requestb.in/) para ver en que difieren con la que ya funciona creada desde postman.

Comment: no puedo mirar los logs del servicio porque no tengo acceso al servidor, pero me lo van a mirar. Mientras tanto tenia dudas de si esta era la forma correcta de añadir el token a la petición. Añadido tag c# y el using que faltaba en la funcion

Comment: **actualización** la key que me han pasado es: IDENTITY_KEY
pero me sigue fallando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final funciono con Add:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("IDENTITY_KEY", AuthToken);
```

Esto ocurre porque el servicio no usaba el Authorization header , habia que pasar solo el 'key' del header como 'IDENTITY_KEY' , asi en los headers queda como IDENTITY_KEY: token